# Converting c++ project to clr safe project

Tags: c++-cli, porting

I need to work on converting a very huge c++ project to clr safe. The current c++ project has a lot of stuff from c++ like templates, generics, pointers, storage/stream, ole apis, zlib compression apis, inlines etc. Where can I find the datiled document for this type of conversion? Can you suggest some good book to refer to? If anyone of you have done such conversion, can I get some analysis from you?

Answer (score 2):

I'll just cough up the MSDN Library article titled "How to: Migrate to /clr:safe

Visual C++ can generate verifiable components with using /clr:safe, which causes the compiler to generate errors for each non-verifiable code construct.

The following issues generate verifiability errors:

- Native types. Even if it isn't used, the declaration of native classes, structures, pointers, or arrays will prevent compilation.
- Global variables
- Function calls into any unmanaged library, including common language runtime function calls
- A verifiable function cannot contain a static_cast Operator for down-casting. The static_cast operator can be used for casting between primitive types, but for down-casting, safe_cast or a C-Style cast (which is implemented as a safe_cast) must be used.
- A verifiable function cannot contain a reinterpret_cast operator (or any C-style cast equivalent).
- A verifiable function cannot perform arithmetic on an interior_ptr. It may only assign to it and dereference it.
- A verifiable function can only throw or catch pointers to reference types, so value types must be boxed before throwing.
- A verifiable function can only call verifiable functions (such that calls to the common language runtime are not allowed, include AtEntry/AtExit, and so global constructors are disallowed).
- A verifiable class cannot use Explicit.
- If building an EXE, a main function cannot declare any parameters, so GetCommandLineArgs must be used to retrieve command-line arguments.
- Making a non-virtual call to a virtual function.

Also, the following keywords cannot be used in verifiable code:

- unmanaged and pack pragmas
- naked and align __declspec modifiers
- __asm
- __based
- __try and __except

I reckon that will keep you busy for a while.  There is no magic wand to wave to turn native C++ into verifiable code.  Are you sure this is worth the investment?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of native C++ is entirely valid C++/CLI, including templates, inlines, etc, except the CLR STL is rather slow compared to the BCL. Also, native C++ doesn't have generics, only templates.

The reality of compiling as C++/CLI is to check the switch and push compile, and wait for it to throw errors.

Comment: The vast majority of C++ is C++/CLI, but not "safe" C++/CLI. Anything that touches native classes or pointers is invalid in "safe" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting native C++ into *safe* C++/CLI will result in a code that is syntactically different, but semantically same as C#. If that is the case, why not rewrite directly in C#?

If you want to avoid what is essentially a complete rewrite, consider the following alternatives:

- **P/Invoke**. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar whether this would isolate safe from unsafe code. Even if it can perform the isolation, you'll need to wrap your existing C++ code into procedural, C-like API, so it can be consumed by P/Invoke. On a plus side, unless your API is excessively chatty, you get to keep (most of) your native performance.
- Wrapping your C++ into **out-of-process COM server** and using COM Interop to consume it from the manged code. This way, your managed code is completely protected from any corruption that might happen at C++ end and can remain "safe". The downside is a performance hit that you'll get for out-of-process marshaling and the implementation effort you'll need to expend to correctly implement the COM.

Comment: templates, p/invoke using native header files, stack semantics for better management of disposable objects, C++/CLI actually has a lot of capability that C# doesn't.  It's arguable whether this makes up for the clunkier property and event syntax, etc.